# Accessing a Class in an Abstract Class' member in C++

Tags: c++, class, abstract, point, shapes

I have a class Point as shown here:

```
class Point {
private:

    int x,y;

public:


    Point(int x, int y){
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
    }

    Point(Point &copy){
        x = copy.getX(); 
        y = copy.getY();
    }

    int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    void setX(int setx){
        x = setx;
    }

    void setY(int sety){
        y = sety;
    }


    void print(){
        cout << "(" << getX() << "," << getY() << ")" << endl;
    }
};
```

I'm attempting to make an Abstract class called GeometricShape that is able to utilize a point in it's constructor, and then call upon that point in it's members.

I've attempted to declare a Point, and then utilize the copy constructor to construct the GeometricShape. However I cant seem to get this to work without getting an "no matching function for call to 'Point::Point()' GeometricShape(Point coord).

I've also tried to declare the point in the constructor with:

```
 Point ShapePoint = coord;
```

but then I am unable to access the ShapePoint in the print member.

Here is where I currently am at:

```
class GeometricShape{

    Point ShapePoint;

public:

    GeometricShape(Point coord){
        ShapePoint = Point(coord);

    }

    virtual float getArea(){
        return 0;
    }

    virtual float getPerimeter(){
        return 0;
    }

    virtual void print(){
        ShapePoint.print();
    }

};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your post does not seem to contain a question (where is the question-mark?). I guess your question is:

'How do I get rid of this compilation error "no matching function for call to 'Point::Point()' GeometricShape(Point coord)"?'

To that question, Nico Schertler provided an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59111686/2323908

Answer (score 2):

Use a member initializer

```
GeometricShape(Point coord) 
    : ShapePoint(coord)
{

}
```

I would also advice to take the point as const reference `const Point& coord` to avoid unnecessary copies in memory.

Comment: [Documentation page for Member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) for those seeking more details.